# require.js runtime error when importing angular 2

Tags: required, angular, typescript1.5

I'm trying to run a typescript project (I'm using vs2012) and to import angular 2.
the projects is set to AMD module system and ECMAcript 5

*In ts filed I'm importing the module:*
import ng2 = require('angular2/angular2');

=> *in js file it replaced to:*
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {

And I'm getting this require.js runtime error:

```
 Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (require, exports) {
   ....
   // code 
   ....
}
```

Is anyone knows what the cause of it?

Thanks a lot!
Lior

Answer (score 0):

Try using the new ES6 syntax for importing files.

Example: `import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';`

This [Angular2 Visual Studio tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/03/12/a-preview-of-angular-2-and-typescript-in-visual-studio.aspx) can help you setup your project.